# Data Studio Apps Script - Default Config / Set Config Value

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I have a config process that has multiple steps. For most users, the first and second steps only have 1 option, so I would like to do something like `cc.setConfigParams({...})` to update the config's current value, but this seems not possible.

To do "default" config in other places, I use a config option (in SELECT_SINGLE) with `value=""`, but in this case, I need to know what the value was, so I can't use empty string.

I've looked over the documentation and couldn't find anything related - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/data-studio/config

Answer (score 0):

Default values are not currently supported for community connector configs. If you're interested in seeing this feature added, please [file an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:321382).

Comment: I opened an issue - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149579142 - and someone replied there is a way to pass the config in the URL as parameters.
I tried many ways to do so without success. Are you aware of such way?